# share variable between functions

Tags: c++, function, variables, global-variables

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void lemo(){
    int shamble;
}

int main(){
    lemo();
    shamble= 2;
    cout<<shamble;
    return 0;
}
```

All I want is call a variable from other function.
After executing console will say:

`'shamble' was not declared in this scope`

What can I do for this problem?

Use variable and list of objects in other files and functions.

Comment: Put them at the top of the code to make them global (outside of the functions)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list#388282

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your compiler is correct. `shamble` was *not* declared within the scope of `main`. As it stands your `lemo` function does nothing. It declares an unused *local* variable and then exits.

You could just as well write the following, and it would actually compile.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int shamble = 2;
    std::cout << shamble;
    return 0;
}
```

If you want a variable to be available to multiple functions, it *can* be declared "globally" but *don't*. This rapidly leads to code that is difficult to reason about and troubleshoot.

Rather you should pass information from one function to another via arguments and return values. Or you may wish to encapsulate that persistent state into objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can move the declaration of the `shamble` variable into `main()`, and then pass it into `lemo()` for it to use, eg:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void lemo(int &shamble){
    shamble = 2;
}

int main(){
    int shamble;
    lemo(shamble);
    cout << shamble;
    return 0;
}
```